# setting the timezone in octobercms with twig

Tags: twig, octobercms

Hello i have a question about setting the timezone in october cms.
My date keeps giving the out of an english format.

I hope anyone can help me with this.

```html
{{ record.date|date("D d F", "Europe/Amsterdam") }}
```

This is my little piece of code but the output is just not right.
Hope someone can show me how.

Answer (score -2):

Set up in twig_extension timezone.

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->getExtension('Twig_Extension_Core')->setTimezone('Europe/Paris');
```